# How to build navigation links from records from a database

Tags: php, zend-framework

When you list records from tables in database, what is the method to use to build navigation links??

Is it:

```
$paginator->setPages();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination links are rendered from a phtml template file. 
Example

```
<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<div class="paginationControl">
<!-- Previous page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->previous)); ?>">
&lt; Previous
</a> |
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">&lt; Previous</span> |
<?php endif; ?>

<!-- Numbered page links -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
<?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $page)); ?>">
<?php echo $page; ?>
</a> |
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $page; ?> |
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<!-- Next page link -->
<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => $this->next)); ?>">
Next &gt;
</a>
<?php else: ?>
<span class="disabled">Next &gt;</span>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```